# how can get radio value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

how can get radio value in Flutter?

I writing this code and tring to get value, but has a little problems.

Code

```
enum SingingCharacter { Australia, USA }

SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.Australia;

String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
      username: _usernameController.text,
      bio: _bioController.text,
      file: _image!,
      country: _character.toString(),
    );

Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
                    title: const Text('Australia'),
                    value: SingingCharacter.Australia,
                    groupValue: _character,
                    onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _character = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
                    title: const Text('USA'),
                    value: SingingCharacter.USA,
                    groupValue: _character,
                    onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _character = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

When the use register and choose the country, I will got this value `SingingCharacter.Australia` and writing firebase, but I hope I could got like this value `Australia` or `USA`, not got  `SingingCharacter.Australia` or `SingingCharacter.USA`

Where is my falut code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the `RadioListTile<T>` where `T` as `SingingCharacter`. So you will get the value as `SingingCharacter.USA` or `SingingCharacter.Australia`. If you want only the name, try like below.

```
onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
 setState(() {
  if (value != null) {
     _character = value;
     String enumValue = value.name; // USA
     // or
     enumValue = describeEnum(value); // USA
  }
 });
}
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html

Comment: I'd tried to used this `country: _character.toString(),` change to `enumValue`, but it's show me Undefined name 'enumValue'

Comment: For understanding purposes, I have shown you using an internal variable. To use it out of the widget, use a field or update it as like `country: _character.name`.

Answer (score 0):

For a flexible solution, perhaps you can leverage [extension](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods), something like this:

```
enum SingingCharacter { Australia, USA }

extension SingingCharacterExt on SingingCharacter {

  String get code {
    switch (this) {
      case SingingCharacter.Australia:
        return "AU";
      case SingingCharacter.USA:
        return "US";
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
debugPrint(SingingCharacter.Australia.code);
```

Comment: extension need to add where?